# Complex Laravel 5 group by on collection

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, grouping

I have a collection 'Event' that has a relation of 'Site' & 'Inspection'.

What I want to do is group all events for on 'Inspection Date' and then under this group the events by 'Site'.

I.E

- Inspection Date (YYYY-MM-DD)

  - Site 1

    - Event Name
    - Event Name
  - Site 2

    - Event Name
- Inspection Date (YYYY-MM-DD)

  - Site 1

    - Event Name

And once I have this grouping, I want to output an array like:

```
[
  'title => 'Site Name: Event Name, Event Name, Event Name', 
  'date' => 'YYYY-MM-DD'
]
```

This is well above my intelligence so any help will be appreciated! BTW I am using Postgresql so it seems I can only use groupBy on the id's?

I have attempted a few thing using groupBy() and map(), which seems to kinda get me somewhere but not sure how to proceed:

```
$events = $events->groupBy('inspection.id')->map(function($item){
    return $item->groupBy('site.id');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the structure (simplified to array):

```php
$events = [
   'name' => 'event name',
   'inspection' => ['date' => ' ... '] // relation
   'site' => ['name' => ' ... ']       // relation
```

this is what you need:

```php
$collection
   ->groupBy('inspection.date')
   ->map(function ($events, $date) { 
       return $events
          ->groupBy('site.name')
          ->map(function ($events, $site) use ($date) { 
               return [
                  'title' => $site_name.': '.$events->implode('name', ', '), 
                  'date' => $date
               ];
          }); 
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am getting the error message: 

`array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer`

Something to do with Postgresql?

Comment: Nope, it's likely that you pass key that's in fact an object. Paste the code

Comment: It is definitely the date causing issues as I can use groupBy on something like ('inspection.name') or ('inspection.id') but not inspection.date - is there anyway I can convert the date to a string within the groupBy closure?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, managed to get this working by using: 
`->groupBy(function($events){
     return $events->inspection->inspected_at->format('Y-m-d');
 })` Now what I want to do is get another relation on the event (EventType) and implode `$event->eventType->name to 'title'` - any ideas on this?